# Can we add a new stage in .gitlab-ci other than the stages from the template file

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a template file which has few stages like:

template.yaml

```
stages:
    - a2
    - a3
```

Now, I have another file .gitlab-ci.yaml which should include stages from above template file, but also needs few more stages:

```
include:
  - project: 'path to repo'
    ref: main
    file: "/template.yml"

stages:
  - a1

job1:
   stage: a1

job2:
  stage: a2
```

I get the following error:

```
 chosen stage does not exist; available stages are .pre, a1, .post
```

Is it possible to do something similar without making any changes in the template file ?

Answer (score 2):

Gitlab does not support merging of arrays, likely since it would have no idea which order the merged array is supposed to be in: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#override-included-configuration-arrays

Therefore, you just need to manually include the full contents of any arrays that you are redefining. For your example:

```
include:
  - project: 'path to repo'
    ref: main
    file: "/template.yml"

stages:
  - a1
  - a2
  - a3

job1:
   stage: a1

job2:
  stage: a2
```